# place content (content-title) from page into the <li><a> on another page

Tags: php, jquery, menu, title

HI, I'm trying to do the following.

```
<!-- html-->

    <head>
      <title>(place current content-title-page) - lalala.com</title>
    </head>

<!-- html [end] -->
<!-- menu page -->

    <ul> 
      <li>
        <a href="page-1.php">(place content-title-1)</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="page-2.php">(place content-title-2)</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="page-3.php">(place content-title-3)</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

<!-- menu page [END] -->
<!-- Page-1 -->

    <div id="content-container">
      <div id="page-title">CONTENT TITLE - 1</div>
      <div class="content-block">content tekst</div>
    </div>

<!-- Page-1 [END] -->
```

So, i'm trying to place the content-title's of all the corresponding pages in the menu and place the current content-title into the `<title>`

Can someone help me out?

Thanks,

Comment: Not until you tell us where these titles come from. If you have them in a database, or in an array, or some other data structure you can easily do this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your page, with value placeholders, is contained in a variable $templates:

```
... <title>${title_placeholder}</title>...
```

To insert desired page title instead of the placeholder you could use the str_replace statement in the following way:

```
$template = str_replace(
    array('This is the title', ...),
    array('${title_placeholder}', ...),
    $template
);
```